# Navigation Jetpack Compose: IllegalArgumentException: No destination with ID is on the NavController's back stack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

In my application, I want to be able to navigate to the CodeDetails screen from different places (from History and from Scanner). I made 2 nested navigation graphs. As a result, I can successfully move from the History screen to the CodeDetails screen, but when I move from the Scanner screen, I get an application crash with an error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No destination with ID -1689679215 is on the NavController's back stack. The current destination is Destination(0x4a873559) route=code_details/{code_id}  at androidx.navigation.NavController.getBackStackEntry(NavController.kt:2209)   at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack(NavController.kt:1918) at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack$default(NavController.kt:1813) at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1721)   at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1719)   at androidx.navigation.NavController$NavControllerNavigatorState.push(NavController.kt:287) at androidx.navigation.NavigatorState.pushWithTransition(NavigatorState.kt:88)  at androidx.navigation.compose.ComposeNavigator.navigate(ComposeNavigator.kt:50)    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateInternal(NavController.kt:260) at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1719)    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1662)    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1984)    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:1979)    at com.t_ovchinnikova.android.scandroid_2.navigation.NavigationState.navigateToCodeDetails(NavigationState.kt:24)   at com.t_ovchinnikova.android.scandroid_2.ui.MainScreenKt$MainScreen$2$1$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:34) at com.t_ovchinnikova.android.scandroid_2.ui.MainScreenKt$MainScreen$2$1$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:31) at com.t_ovchinnikova.android.scandroid_2.presentation.viewmodel.ScanningViewModel$handleCode$1.invokeSuspend(ScanningViewModel.kt:67)  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)   at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7542)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@f1fcaaf, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]

Graph for scanner:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.scannerScreenNavGraph(
    scannerScreenContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    codeDetailsScreenContent: @Composable (codeId: UUID) -> Unit
) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = Screen.Scanner.route,
        route = Screen.ScannerMain.route
    ) {
        composable(Screen.Scanner.route) {
            scannerScreenContent()
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.CodeDetails.route,
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(KEY_CODE_ID) {
                    type = CodeNavigationType
                }
            )
        ) {
            val codeId = it.arguments?.getSerializable(KEY_CODE_ID) as UUID?
                ?: throw RuntimeException("Args is null")
            codeDetailsScreenContent(codeId)
        }
    }
}
```

Graph for history

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.historyScreenNavGraph(
    historyScreenContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    codeDetailsScreenContent: @Composable (codeId: UUID) -> Unit
) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = Screen.History.route,
        route = Screen.HistoryMain.route
    ) {
        composable(Screen.History.route) {
            historyScreenContent()
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.CodeDetails.route,
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(Screen.KEY_CODE_ID) {
                    type = CodeNavigationType
                }
            )
        ) {
            val codeId = it.arguments?.getSerializable(Screen.KEY_CODE_ID) as UUID?
                ?: throw RuntimeException("Args is null")
            codeDetailsScreenContent(codeId)
        }
    }
}
```

AppNavGraph

```
@Composable
fun AppNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    scannerScreenContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    codeDetailsScreenContent: @Composable (codeId: UUID) -> Unit,
    historyScreenContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    settingsScreenContent: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navHostController,
        startDestination = Screen.ScannerMain.route
    ) {
        historyScreenNavGraph(
            historyScreenContent,
            codeDetailsScreenContent
        )
        scannerScreenNavGraph(
            scannerScreenContent,
            codeDetailsScreenContent
        )
        composable(Screen.Settings.route) {
            settingsScreenContent()
        }
    }
}
```

Screens

```
sealed class Screen(
    val route: String
) {
    object ScannerMain : Screen(ROUTE_SCANNER_MAIN)
    object Scanner : Screen(ROUTE_SCANNER)
    object CodeDetails : Screen(ROUTE_CODE_DETAILS) {

        private const val ROUTE_FOR_ARGS = "code_details"

        fun getRouteWithArgs(codeId: UUID): String {
            return "$ROUTE_FOR_ARGS/$codeId"
        }
    }
    object HistoryMain : Screen(ROUTE_HISTORY_MAIN)
    object History : Screen(ROUTE_HISTORY)
    object Settings : Screen(ROUTE_SETTINGS)

    companion object {
        const val KEY_CODE_ID = "code_id"

        const val ROUTE_SCANNER_MAIN = "main"
        const val ROUTE_SCANNER = "scanner"
        const val ROUTE_CODE_DETAILS = "code_details/{$KEY_CODE_ID}"
        const val ROUTE_HISTORY = "history"
        const val ROUTE_HISTORY_MAIN = "history_main"
        const val ROUTE_SETTINGS = "settings"
    }
}
```

```
class NavigationState(
    val navHostController: NavHostController
) {
    fun navigateTo(route: String) {
        navHostController.navigate(route) {
            popUpTo(navHostController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                saveState = true
            }
            launchSingleTop = true
            restoreState = true
        }
    }

    fun navigateToCodeDetails(codeId: UUID) {
        navHostController.navigate(Screen.CodeDetails.getRouteWithArgs(codeId))
    }
}
```

My MainScreen

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {

    val navigationState = rememberNavigationState()

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomBar(navigationState)
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->  
        AppNavGraph(
            navHostController = navigationState.navHostController,
            scannerScreenContent = {
                ScannerScreen(
                    paddingValues = paddingValues,
                    onScanListener = {
                        navigationState.navigateToCodeDetails(it)
                    }
                )
            },
            codeDetailsScreenContent = {
                CodeDetailsScreen(
                    codeId = it,
                    onBackPressed = {
                        navigationState.navHostController.popBackStack()
                    }
                )
            },
            historyScreenContent = {
                HistoryScreen(
                    codeItemClickListener = {
                        navigationState.navigateToCodeDetails(it)
                    }
                )
            },
            settingsScreenContent = {
                SettingsScreen()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

If I create a separate class with a different route and a separate method for navigating to the details screen, then everything works successfully. But why can't I use the same route to go from different places to the same screen?

```
@Composable
fun AppNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    scannerScreenContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    codeDetailsScreenContent: @Composable (codeId: UUID) -> Unit,
    historyScreenContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    settingsScreenContent: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navHostController,
        startDestination = Screen.ScannerMain.route
    ) {
        scannerScreenNavGraph(
            scannerScreenContent,
            codeDetailsScreenContent
        )
        historyScreenNavGraph(
            historyScreenContent,
            codeDetailsScreenContent
        )
        composable(Screen.Settings.route) {
            settingsScreenContent()
        }
    }
}

fun NavGraphBuilder.historyScreenNavGraph(
    historyScreenContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    codeDetailsScreenContent: @Composable (codeId: UUID) -> Unit
) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = Screen.History.route,
        route = Screen.HistoryMain.route
    ) {
        composable(Screen.History.route) {
            historyScreenContent()
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.HistoryCodeDetails.route,
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(Screen.KEY_CODE_ID) {
                    type = CodeNavigationType
                }
            )
        ) {
            val codeId = it.arguments?.getSerializable(Screen.KEY_CODE_ID) as UUID?
                ?: throw RuntimeException("Args is null")
            codeDetailsScreenContent(codeId)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
...
            historyScreenContent = {
                HistoryScreen(
                    codeItemClickListener = {
                        navigationState.navigateToHistoryCodeDetails(it)
                    }
                )
            },
...
}

class NavigationState(
    val navHostController: NavHostController
) {
    fun navigateTo(route: String) {
        navHostController.navigate(route) {
            popUpTo(navHostController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                saveState = true
            }
            launchSingleTop = true
            restoreState = true
        }
    }

    fun navigateToCodeDetails(codeId: UUID) {
        navHostController.navigate(Screen.CodeDetails.getRouteWithArgs(codeId))
    }

    fun navigateToHistoryCodeDetails(codeId: UUID) {
        navHostController.navigate(Screen.HistoryCodeDetails.getRouteWithArgs(codeId))
    }
}

sealed class Screen(
    val route: String
) {
    object ScannerMain : Screen(ROUTE_SCANNER_MAIN)
    object Scanner : Screen(ROUTE_SCANNER)
    object CodeDetails : Screen(ROUTE_CODE_DETAILS) {

        private const val ROUTE_FOR_ARGS = "code_details"

        fun getRouteWithArgs(codeId: UUID): String {
            return "$ROUTE_FOR_ARGS/$codeId"
        }
    }
    object HistoryCodeDetails : Screen(ROUTE_CODE_INFO_FROM_HISTORY) {

        private const val ROUTE_FOR_ARGS = "history_code_details"

        fun getRouteWithArgs(codeId: UUID): String {
            return "$ROUTE_FOR_ARGS/$codeId"
        }
    }
    object HistoryMain : Screen(ROUTE_HISTORY_MAIN)
    object History : Screen(ROUTE_HISTORY)
    object Settings : Screen(ROUTE_SETTINGS)

    companion object {
        const val KEY_CODE_ID = "code_id"

        const val ROUTE_SCANNER_MAIN = "main"
        const val ROUTE_SCANNER = "scanner"
        const val ROUTE_CODE_DETAILS = "code_details/{$KEY_CODE_ID}"
        const val ROUTE_CODE_INFO_FROM_HISTORY = "history_code_details/{$KEY_CODE_ID}"
        const val ROUTE_HISTORY = "history"
        const val ROUTE_HISTORY_MAIN = "history_main"
        const val ROUTE_SETTINGS = "settings"
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is so separated and hard to read. It'd be nicer if you can shorten the size of code.

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to change routes' name to

```
const val ROUTE_SCANNER_MAIN = "main"
const val ROUTE_SCANNER = "scanner"
const val ROUTE_CODE_DETAILS = "code_details"
const val ROUTE_CODE_INFO_FROM_HISTORY = "history_code_details"
const val ROUTE_HISTORY = "history"
const val ROUTE_HISTORY_MAIN = "history_main"
const val ROUTE_SETTINGS = "settings"
```

And use these for the path. For example,

```
object CodeDetails : Screen(ROUTE_CODE_DETAILS) {
    private const val ROUTE_FOR_ARGS = "code_details"

    fun getRouteWithArgs(codeId: UUID): String {
        return "$ROUTE_FOR_ARGS/$codeId"
    }
}
```

This part should be changed to

```
object CodeDetails : Screen(ROUTE_CODE_DETAILS) {
    fun getRouteWithArgs(codeId: UUID): String {
        return "$ROUTE_CODE_DETAILS/$codeId"
    }
}
```

And for the passing data between graphs, you better keep that data in the global state data and reuse it.

Otherwise, you can check [this source code](https://github.com/Zhuinden/jetpack-navigation-ftue-compose-sample/blob/cc571bf83cb60c4f84595bb341fa8569de1e05f1/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/jetpacknavigationftuecomposeexample/application/AppNavGraph.kt#L95-L96)

Here's the short snippet from the file.

```
navigation(startDestination = Routes.DESTINATION_PROFILE, route="${Routes.NAVIGATION_LOGGED_IN}/{${Routes.NAVIGATION_LOGGED_IN_ARG_USERNAME}}") {
                composable(route = Routes.DESTINATION_PROFILE) { navBackStackEntry ->
                    val profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel(viewModelStoreOwner = navBackStackEntry)

                    val username = navBackStackEntry.arguments!!.getString("username")!!

                    ProfileScreen(profileViewModel, username)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the question is not how to pass the data, but why can't I use the same route to go to a specific screen from different places. Perhaps you can explain how your answer can help me?